# log canonical surface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

For a log cannonical surface singularity, I guess there is classification about the configuration of the exceptional divisor of its minimal resolution. I wonder if there is some specific example or something like local model map about the resolution. For example, how to contract one elliptic curve to get a log cannonical surface singularity. Thanks in advance.